# Show a dictionary when long-pressing a word

Tags: dictionary

I have a Kindle app. My favorite thing about it is that I can long-press any word and a dictionary pops up for me.

I am wondering if there's an app that does that for my phone. So if I'm reading a research paper or something, I can use the same feature across all mediums of news and reading.

I've looked around and found lots of apps for dictionaries, but I want an interactive one.

Does anyone know if that exists?

Comment: The reason that long presses for a dictionary function works there is because it is a simple OS working only as a reader app. Long-press in the Android OS has an entirely different meaning. For something to happen across all apps like you describe, the program would have to layer atop the operating system to subvert the operating system level's interpretation of that event. Anything the OS does from that keypress would become unavailable, unless the layered program passes it through after evaluating the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app-Flying Dictionary on the Play Store which does the same things that are your needs. It works similar to the Kindle feature. Go try it out!

Comment: You probably mean "Fly" Dictionary. The reviews report this app to be buggy, especially those reporting about this pop-up functionality.

Comment: I personally use the app on a daily basis and it works great for me. My comment was solely on the basis of my user experience!